# 3D arrays and member functions to check winner to 3D tic-tac-toe

Tags: arrays, function, member

first post here. I'm creating a 3D tic-tac-toe c++ program. My checkWin member function is causing problems. I am curious as to why the test rows nested for loops do not give a winner when the if statement has been satisfied but the test colums and diagonals work fine for layer0. Thanks

```
void TicTacToe::checkWin(void) {
char returnValue = ' ';
//test for X or O win
//test rows, does not work
for (int k=0; k<=2; k++){
    for (int i=0; i<=2; i++){
        if ( (space[i][0][k] == space[i][1][k]) && (space[i][0][k] == space[i][2][k]) ){
            returnValue = space[i][0][k];
        }
    }
}
int k=0;  //test layer 0 only
//test columns
if ( (space[0][0][k] == space[1][0][k]) && (space[0][0][k] == space[2][0][k]) )
     returnValue = space[0][0][k];
else if ( (space[0][1][k] == space[1][1][k]) && (space[0][1][k] == space[2][1][k]) )
     returnValue = space[0][1][k];
else if ( (space[0][2][k] == space[1][2][k]) && (space[0][2][k] == space[2][2][k]) )
     returnValue = space[0][2][k];


//test diagonals
else if ( (space[0][0][k] == space[1][1][k]) && (space[0][0][k] == space[2][2][k]) )
     returnValue = space[0][0][k];
else if ( (space[0][2][k] == space[1][1][k]) && (space[0][2][k] == space[2][0][k]) )
     returnValue = space[0][2][k];

if ( returnValue == ' ' ) { //then test for cat
   int i, j, k, catCheck=0;
   for (i=0; i<=2; i++) {
       for (j=0; j<=2; j++) {
            for (k=0; k<=2; k++) {
                if (space[i][j][k] == ' ' )
                catCheck++;
            }
       }
   }
   if ( catCheck == 0 )
      returnValue = 'C';
}

winner = returnValue;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Probably because you should break out of that loop when you find a winner (all three equal to eachother, but not equal to ' '). Even if you find a winner first, if an empty set of three occurs after that, it satisfies the condition but stores a blank in returnvalue, overwriting the previously found winning x or o. Or you could add `... != ' '` to your condition there, because you really don't care if all three are empty at that point. Stepping through a debugger or adding temporary diagnostics print outs could really help you here.

Just a guess at a glance.

Comment: Well I didnt mean to cw that, but whatever. Fat fingers on a touch screen.